# Force Vagrant to use Swap memory

Tags: out-of-memory, vagrant, osx-yosemite

I have one of those first alu iMacs with 2+2 GB ram. I use Vagrant to emulate advanced development environments, separated for different jobs.

When I have just one vagrant process running in the background, the computer gets to be slow as hell, because it is always out of memory.

The question is: **can I use vagrant (or any app) to run only on swap memory, so it leaves all the memory for the os and other apps?**

If there is any solution, how can I do that?

Comment: How old is your iMacs, 4 GB is fine for both host and vagrant instances. Maybe the slow is not related with memory at all.

Comment: @BMW it's a late 2007 or 2008 maybe. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **No, a process can not run in swap completely.**

Processes must have their data in RAM for the CPU to be able to operate on it, infrequently used data is moved out to swap space when there's no longer space available in memory for everything that's loaded.

You could create a larger swap space and use `ulimit` to limit the amount of memory used by processes (i.e. force them into swap earlier), but this doesn't really address the root of your problem - that you're pretty much at the limit of your 4GB of memory.

Keep in mind that using swap space will always produce performance problems as (even with SSDs) reading from disk is far slower than reading from memory.

Short of upgrading to more memory, you could:

- Reduce the amount of memory allocated by your vagrant box;
- Use OS X's *Activity Monitor* to identify and close any programs/processes that are not in use but are still using memory.

but, again, these are just stop-gap solutions.

Comment: - Sadly 4 GB is the maximum supported memory size. - I'm gonna try out the `ulimit` thing asap. - If vagrant is the only app, the system is still dying, because of lack of memory. :(

Comment: can you send me an example of how you think, I should use `ulimit`?

Comment: A quick example would be: `$ ulimit -Sv 500000; $ vagrant up` This would set the _virtual memory_ maximum to 500mb. You may get bigger returns just by closing unused / unnecessary applications (like Chrome). You may also want to check the amount memory allocated by your vagrant box (i.e. if the VM is set up to use 2-4GB of memory, you might want to reduce that).

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no.

Control swappiness has to be done within the VM, for example Linux, `echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` to set swap strategy to most aggressive mode. Remember, you have no control over where processes are running (physical memory VS swap)

However, by doing this, your host/guest will still be slow as hell as simply you don't have enough physical memory.

The ultimate solution is to add more RAM to your iMAC ;-D

Comment: Yeah, the solution is that. But it (officially) supports only 4 gb and I didn't find any in Hungary, so I don't order something from abroad that is not sure to work. :( Thanks for the information!